# How to include code from a file in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, include

I'm new to Ruby and I'm figuring out how to include a file in a script. I tried `require` and `include` but it doesn't work.

Here's the file I'd like to include, worth noting that it's not a module.

```
# file1.rb
if Constants.elementExist(driver, 'Allow') == true
  allowElement = driver.find_element(:id, 'Allow')
  allowElement.click()
  sleep 1
  wait.until {
    driver.find_element(:id, 'Ok').click()
  }
  username = driver.find_element(:id, 'UsernameInput')
  username.clear
  username.send_keys Constants.itech_email
  password = driver.find_element(:id, 'PasswordInput')
  password.clear
  password.send_keys Constants.itechPass
  driver.find_element(:id, 'Login').click
else
  username = driver.find_element(:id, 'UsernameInput')
  username.clear
  username.send_keys Constants.itech_email
  password = driver.find_element(:id, 'PasswordInput')
  password.clear
  password.send_keys Constants.itechPass
  driver.find_element(:id, 'Login').click
end
```

That file contains several lines of codes that are reusable or repeatable in my case. It's not inside a class or a module. It's a straightforward Ruby script, and I'd like to use this on my second script inside a module.

```
# file2.rb
module File2
  module IOS
    # include file1.rb
  end
end
```

This way, it should just run the code of `file1.rb` inside `file2.rb`.

How can I do this in Ruby?

Comment: I'd suggest you provide more context to what you're trying to achieve with the code, since you could have scoping issues on `file2.rb` with undefined objects/classes in `file1.rb` such as `driver`, `password` or `Constants`.

Comment: even if you manage to "include" this file in your namespace what is it exactly that you anticipate happening? At this point, barring the comments made by @Oxfist, you might as well just use `ruby file1.rb` from the command line or `load` in a script.

Answer (score 0):

According to the [Ruby docs](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.2/Kernel.html#method-i-require), `require` has the following behavior:

> If the filename does not resolve to an absolute path, it will be
>   searched for in the directories listed in `$LOAD_PATH ($:)`.

Which means that in order to run `file1.rb`'s code inside `file2.rb`, where both files are in the exact same folder, you'd have to do the following:

```
# file2.rb
module File2
  module IOS
    # Absolute path to file1.rb, adding '.rb' is optional
    require './file1'
  end
end
```

Comment: I tried that before

require 'file1'

butt it didn't work. Their in the same path/directory btw.

Comment: @ジョンピーター update the question and post the error you're getting so I can help you

Comment: "butt it didn't work". Include an **error message**. There are a million different ways it might not work and you still haven't said which it is

Comment: The problem here is that it is very unlikely that the OP has the directory in `$LOAD_PATH`. To assist with this ruby has provided a similar method for requiring files relative to the calling file `require_relative` which I think is more what you were intending

Answer (score 0):

use [require_relative](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.1/Kernel.html#method-i-require_relative):

`require_relative 'file1.rb'`